# Why do we need these "explicit" catch blocks?

Tags: java, exception

I am learning Exception Handling in Java using the tutorials on beginnersbook.com.

What is the utility of [this code here:](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/)

```
class Example1 {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int num1, num2;
      try {
         /* We suspect that this block of statement can throw 
          * exception so we handled it by placing these statements
          * inside try and handled the exception in catch block
          */
         num1 = 0;
         num2 = 62 / num1;
         System.out.println(num2);
         System.out.println("Hey I'm at the end of try block");
      }
      catch (ArithmeticException e) { 
         /* This block will only execute if any Arithmetic exception 
          * occurs in try block
          */
         System.out.println("You should not divide a number by zero");
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         /* This is a generic Exception handler which means it can handle
          * all the exceptions. This will execute if the exception is not
          * handled by previous catch blocks.
          */
         System.out.println("Exception occurred");
      }
      System.out.println("I'm out of try-catch block in Java.");
   }
}
```

This bit:

```
catch (ArithmeticException e) { 
             /* This block will only execute if any Arithmetic exception 
              * occurs in try block
              */
             System.out.println("You should not divide a number by zero");
          }
```

Why do we need this when catch(Exception e){...} is capable of dealing with everything?

The only reason I can think of is displaying the message that *you want/wish to display* because you do not *like* the message given by `e.getmessage()`.

Comment: depends on the `Exception` you catch you will know the kind of error you have. Then you will take different actions depending on what `Exception` has raised. With an unique `Exception e` block you don't  know where the error has come because is too generic. But with `ArithmeticException e` you know that is an `Exception` raised from an arithmetic operation.

Comment: *The only reason I can think of is displaying the message that you want/wish to display because you do not like the message given by e.getmessage()* That **is** the only reason. To do action one on exception type one, and action two on exception type two.

Comment: It is just to show the concept of several `catch` blocks and that more specific `catch` block should come before more generic. But sometimes you may need to treat different types of exceptions differently

Answer (score 1):

This `catch` syntax allows to introduce more specific error handling for more specific exceptions. It's a nice syntax because catch using `Exception` is very generic so one would have to use `if (ex instanceof ArithmeticException)` if this `catch` syntax was not present.

An example could be network error handling. If your client code declares `RetryableException extends NetworkException` you might want to retry client operation when you catch `RetryableException` but don't retry for any other `NetworkException`.

As per [official The catch Blocks docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html):

> Exception handlers can do more than just print error messages or halt the program. They can do error recovery, prompt the user to make a decision, or propagate the error up to a higher-level handler using chained exceptions, as described in the Chained Exceptions section.

Answer (score 0):

As far as good coding practices are concerned in exception handling, we should always catch the nearest/most related checked exception first for a potential exception that may or may not occur at the run-time. 
For e.g. for file operations we will always go for **FileNotFoundException**

The second catch block can be used for a exception that may or may not occur (after the first vulnerable statement has been executed).

In case, we are unsure about the type of exception that may occur at the run time, then we can go with the Generic **Exception** in the catch block.

Here in you example, I guess the author want to convey two capabilities of exception handling:

1. We can use two catch block with a try.
2. The order in which you catch
   the exception. It should always be first the child, then the parent.
   E.g.

   > you are having an argument with your friend, and its under your control to solve it, so obviously you'll fix it there itself, instead of going to your parent and asking them to solve it for you.